# How to make a form builder in flutter with drag and drop functionality for widgets and customise their name, rules, datepicker, time 12/24hrs

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a form builder which should have a functionality of drag and drop feature. Also the widgets when dropped onto the form should have a additional control of changing the particular widgets functions as per their choice. Like for suppose if a time picker has been dropped the person should have option to choose from 12/24hrs clock.

I tried adding the widget in one page but when dragging and dropping them on the form the edit option goes away as it is there in the default page. Please help with a suitable answer.

[image]

The kind of functionality I need

[image: jotlob_example]

[image]

Also you can refer jotform